# Simplify does not work for a certain kind of fraction

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have come up with an expression like this:

`b = (a^49. + a^50.) * Exp[a^(1./2)] / a^(99./2)`

I expect that the large power on the denominator can cancel with that on the numerator, but my Mathematica (version 11.1) fails to do so even after simplifying the original output.

Input:

```
b = (a^49. + a^50.) * Exp[a^(1./2)] / a^(99./2);
Simplify[b, Assumptions -> {a > 0}]
```

Output:

$ \displaystyle \frac{ (a^{49.} + a^{50.}) e^{a^{0.5}} } { a^{49.5} } $

I have tried something similar and find that all of the below give satisfactory results except the last two:

1. `b = (a^49 + a^50) * Exp[a^(1/2)] / a^(99/2 + c)`
2. `b = (a^49. + a^50.) / a^(99./2)`
3. `b = a^49. * Exp[a^(1./2)] / a^(99./2)`
4. `b = (a^49 + a^50) * Exp[a^(1./2)] / a^(99./2)`
5. `b = (a^49 + a^50.) * Exp[a^(1./2)] / a^(48.)`
6. `b = (a^49. + a^50) * Exp[a^(1/2)] / a^(99/2)`
7. `b = (a^49. + a^50) * Exp[a^(1/2)] / a^(48)`

I have no idea why this happens and how this problem can be solved. The problem can be skipped if the numbers are given symbolically but I am unable to do that.

Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: `Simplify[Rationalize[b], Assumptions -> {a > 0}]`

Comment: Try `FullSimplify` instead  of `Simplify`